# D3 draw multiple files in one chart each file represent different line/bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to represent processors usage during a specific period of time, using D3.
I have the data distributed in multiple files, all files have the same format, but each file represent different processor. eg:

*file1.tsv*

```
time  P1
t0    0
t2    1
t3    2
```

*file2.tsv*

```
time  P2
t1    3
t3    4
t4    5
```

I want to draw these data in the same chart, each file data in separate line.
The way D3 suggest in their tutorials to draw multi lines is to import all the processors in one file in such format:

*file-all-proc.tsv*

```
time  P1  P2  P3
t0    1   2   3
t1    3   5   7 
t2    1   3   5
..    .   .   .
```

Do you know if there is a better way to do it than manually merge my files?

Manual merge will not be strait forward, as i should merge data, order them base on time, set zeros for empty fields, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple to do. Define your svg and just build your line for each file.

```
var svg = d3.select('#someDivId').append('svg');

d3.tsv('file1.tsv', function(data) {
  svg.selectAll('.file1')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class','file1')
  .attr('d', linefunction(data))});

d3.tsv('file2.tsv', function(data) {
  svg.selectAll('.file2')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class','file2')
  .attr('d', linefunction(data))});
```

Using this method you can use the class `.file1` and `.file2` to style your lines. You could even use queue.js to load in all files and then just just build your function once. You could even do that here.

```
var filenames = ['file1','file2','file-all-proc'];

function addLine(name) {
 d3.tsv(name+'.tsv', function(data) {
  svg.selectAll('.'+name)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class',name)
  .attr('d', linefunction(data));
}

filenames.forEach(addLines(file));
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, and digging there led me to dimple.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json with all that data before starting to draw the chart.
Or you can create a function that return json, and you will pass it to the draw function.

Comment: well still not all samples in the different files got collected in the same time, so i will not have P1, and P2 fields in all rows. which will break d3 i think.
D3 will not accept null values

Comment: You can check when you draw, when you have to set x,y for sure you will use function, check inside it

Comment: yes this should work, I will go with it if no other direct way!

but still I think that D3 should have better way to do it. Its a common use to draw a multi line chart, while each line is represented by different file.

Comment: But as d3, I suggest you to pre-process all file to draw your chart